# How to know where does the sock->ops assigned in kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the code of kernel `linux/net/socket.c`

`sock->ops->bind()`

I can't find where the `sock` or `sock->ops` has been assigned in UDP program.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 2):

This is not done directly as you are expecting. If you look at the code carefully, you will find that the function `sock_from_file(struct file *file, int *err)` is used to assign `file->f_op` to `socket_file_ops`

It is called twice in the code

1. In the `sockfd_lookup(int fd, int *err)` function as `sock = sock_from_file(file, err);`
2. In the `sockfd_lookup_light(int fd, int *err, int *fput_needed)` function as `sock = sock_from_file(f.file, err);`

This `file` is then assigned to `sock->file` inside the `sock_alloc_file(struct socket *sock, int flags, const char *dname)` function.

Comment: This is incorrect. The only thing done in `sock_from_file` is an equality check (`==`), not an assignment (`=`). https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/socket.c#L506

Answer (score 2):

The `proto_ops` structure is overridden in each socket implementation. If you search lxr for `inet_bind` you can see it.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L435

```c
int inet_bind(struct socket *sock, struct sockaddr *uaddr, int addr_len)
{
    struct sock *sk = sock->sk;
    u32 flags = BIND_WITH_LOCK;
    int err;

    /* If the socket has its own bind function then use it. (RAW) */
    if (sk->sk_prot->bind) {
        return sk->sk_prot->bind(sk, uaddr, addr_len);
    }
    if (addr_len < sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
        return -EINVAL;

    /* BPF prog is run before any checks are done so that if the prog
     * changes context in a wrong way it will be caught.
     */
    err = BPF_CGROUP_RUN_PROG_INET_BIND_LOCK(sk, uaddr,
                         CGROUP_INET4_BIND, &flags);
    if (err)
        return err;

    return __inet_bind(sk, uaddr, addr_len, flags);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(inet_bind);
```

That is then set in the `proto_ops` structure here -

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L1019

```c
const struct proto_ops inet_stream_ops = {
    .family        = PF_INET,
    .owner         = THIS_MODULE,
    .release       = inet_release,
    .bind          = inet_bind,
    // ...
```